# How to prove it is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $p(x)$ is a polyonmial of degree $n$ (with coefficients in ${\mathbb{Q}}$). If $p(x)$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb{Q}}[x]$ and $a$ is a complex root of $p(x)$. How to show that $1, a, a^2, ..., a^{n-1}$ are linearly independent in ${\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: If they weren't linearly independent, what would this say about the irreducibility of $p(x)$?

Comment: @BrandonThomasVanOver I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose there exist $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ (not all of them are $0$) such that $c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+\dotsb+c_{n-1}a^{n-1}=0$, then what does it say about $a$ being root of a....

Comment: $a$ is a complex root of $p(x)$, I do not see the relation between $ c_0+c_1a+c_2a^2+\dotsb+c_{n-1}a^{n-1}=0$ and $p(x)$. More hint?